# Remove multiple key/value pairs in one postgresql statement

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

folks! I have table Template with only 1 column from type JSON.
column

```json
{
    "name": "any name",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": ["application/json"],
        "ApiSecret": ["keySecret==="],
        "ApiSecretKey": ["key==="],
        "X-Auth-Token": ["token=="],
        "OAUTH-Token": ["token2=="],
        "Authorization": ["basicAuth"]
                },
    "description": "any desc"
}
```

I have to remove all headers like %authorization%, %token%, %apiSecret%.

I created the following query:

```sql
UPDATE template as w
SET 
    column = column::jsonb - ARRAY(select wf.elements
from (select jsonb_object_keys(column->'headers') as elements
    from template) as wf
where LOWER(wf.elements) LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%authorization%','%token%','%apikey%']));
```

Unfortunately  my query does not work. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) You cant't mix jsonb type with array type : `column::jsonb - ARRAY(...)` is not allowed.

(b) If you want to remove several key/value pairs from the same jsonb data, then you have to create a `user-defined aggregate` based on the jsonb `#-` operator :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_remove(x jsonb, y jsonb, p text[])
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$  SELECT COALESCE(x, y) #- p ; $$ ;

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS jsonb_remove_agg(jsonb, text[]) ;
CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_remove_agg(jsonb, text[])
( sfunc = jsonb_remove
, stype = jsonb
) ;
```

Then you can iterate on the new aggregate within a query :

```
UPDATE template as w
SET 
    column = l.elements
FROM
   ( SELECT id -- id is to be replaced by the primary key of table template
          , jsonb_remove_agg(column, array['headers', wf.elements]) as elements
       FROM template
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_object_keys(column->'headers') as wf(elements)
      WHERE LOWER(wf.elements) LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%authorization%','%token%','%apikey%'])
     GROUP BY id -- id is to be replaced by the primary key of table template
   ) AS l
WHERE w.id = l.id ; -- -- id is to be replaced by the primary key of table template
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bbdd43ce93b644252d4c694e724734ce).